# NDK 15 breaks serial port library

Tags: android, android-ndk, serial-port, rs485

I've faced with bad behavior of NDK trying to change and rebuild native serial port libs for COM-port. It is well-known old code, you can find it for example here (not mine)
https://github.com/NanFengyang/AndroidSerialPort/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/SerialPort.c#L126

Pay attention to the string 126 - it is a point of the issue.

NDK15 surprises me twice:

First, this new warning.

> Android NDK: Found platform level in ./project.properties. Setting
>   APP_PLATFORM to android-10. Android NDK: android-10 is unsupported.
>   Using minimum supported version android-14.
>
> Android NDK: WARNING:
>   APP_PLATFORM android-14 is higher than android:minSdkVersion 10 in
>   ./AndroidManifest.xml. NDK binaries will *not* be co mptible with
>   devices older than android-14. See
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md
>   for more information.

Next, while opening COM it fails with this:

> Configuring serial port
>
> tcsetattr() failed (fd = 40, err = 22)

this is the output of my simple dummy code

```
    struct termios cfg;
    LOGD("Configuring serial port");
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &cfg)){
        LOGE("tcgetattr() failed (fd = %d, err = %d)", fd, errno);
    }
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &cfg)){
        LOGE("tcsetattr() failed (fd = %d, err = %d)", fd, errno);
    }
```

This error occurs **only with NDK 15**. It succeed with revisions 14b, 13b, 12b ... for people faced with it too - just download [old NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html#tos-header).

Finally, **the question**.
Error 22 is [**EINVAL**] - *"The optional_actions argument is not a supported value, or an attempt was made to change an attribute represented in the termios structure to an unsupported value".* Does someone know how to avoid it in new NDK?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use NDK **r15**:

1. You can force `NDK_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL=9` (on **ndk-build** command line) to avoid the warning. But NDK does not have **android-10**, and with **r15** you should explicitly choose `APP_PLATFORM=android-9` on command line. FWIW, you can stay with **android-14** unless other parts of your project are not compatible.
2. You should set `APP_DEPRECATED_HEADERS=true`, then headers will be exactly same as **r14**, and you will avoid the bug in unified headers.

There is probably a [bug](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/441) in the unified headers of **r15**, they only set **`TCSANOW`** to **`TCSETS`** for **MIPS**, but not for other ABIs.

The deprecated headers **platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include** etc. [will be removed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ab35684c9ad807f6aefeb3b7532725bafd553ba3/docs/Roadmap.md) in **r16** later this year, or, if in the worst case, in **r17**. The **android-9**—compatible libraries will also probably be gone.

Comment: can you provide an example of where to set APP_DEPRECATED_HEADERS=true, Im not so familiar with it, just know how to run ndk-build and build lib

Comment: If you have Application.mk, you can put it there. Or on ndk-build command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CMake, you should add this code in your module **build.gradle**.

```
 externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                arguments "-DANDROID_DEPRECATED_HEADERS=ON"
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just run ndk-build in terminal. And worst, without gradle (old project). Don't you know what to do in this case? thanks